Is divergence infinite when the source is a single point?
EDIT
Can divergence of a vector field be positive everywhere or almost everywhere?
Can it be positive (but finite) at just one point? Is it the case when the point is the source of gas flow, from which a constant (in $\frac{m^3}s$) stream of gas flows? Or is the divergence actually infinite at that point?
Below are my thoughts, which may contain errors, so if you see any, please explain.

If I understand correctly, in a gas which expands due to heating, the divergence of the velocity field is positive at all points (or at least it can be so). But near any point the contribution to the expansion is infinitesimal. Does it mean that in the case of flow with a single point as the source, the divergence at it would be infinite? I think so, because as you decrease the diameter of the neighbourhood around that point, the flux of velocity through its boundary doesn't tend to $0$.
If so, is there a generalization of divergence that can be formulated using measure theory? Or do physicists generally relegate such considerations to pure mathematics, believing that there are no ideal, single point sources in reality?

Not sure about what you're exactly asking but the following may be useful. For example, point charges are Dirac-delta sources for the electric field.  In general, a point like source is proportional to the Dirac delta distribution. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/591622/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757125/226902 Geometric intuition: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665197/226902

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My attempt, as a newcomer to Physics Stack Exchange and a non-native speaker of English, to present my thoughts on the matter, as expected on SE sites, apparently led to people's confusion. I've therefore edited the question in order to clearly separate what I want to know from what I think is or may be true.

Do you know the Helmholtz decomposition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

I probably did, some time ago… Thanks for bringing it to my attention, @Quillo.

In case you have not understood, Quillo's first comment to you had already answered the entire question in full.

@naturallyInconsistent, so the divergence is infinite at the source in the case of a single point, like the "value" of the Dirac delta is (or its multiple by a finite non-zero number), and zero elsewhere – do I understand correctly?
